# It’s not possible to take text and translate it into a convenient format

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a psychological quiz in REACT. There is text. In a text editor. The text consists of 100 questions and 340 answers. How to make a React program that took at least 2 questions, preferably 10 questions at once, and inserted brackets and other characters so that this data could be taken from an array file? I put a plus sign next to the correct answer.

## As I understand it, regular expressions and  array are needed...

Example-

1. Which of the following concepts corresponds to “Psyche” among the ancient Greeks:

   Nervous system
   +Soul
   Psyche
   Superego
   Consciousness
2. Which of the Greek philosophers admits that the mind depends on the nature of the fire in the soul:

Galen
Socrates

- Heraclitus
  Pythagoras

Data in Data.js-

Example

```
{
 question: ' 1. Which of the following concepts corresponds to “Psyche” among the ancient Greeks: ',
    incorrectAnswers: [
      "Nervous system",
      "psyche",
      "Суперэго",
       "Consciousness", 
       ],
      correctAnswer: "Soul",
  },

  {
    question:
      "2. Which of the Greek philosophers admits that the mind depends on the nature of the fire in the soul: ",
    incorrectAnswers: [
      "Galen",
      "Socrates",
      "Pythagoras“,
    ],
    correctAnswer: "Heraclitus",
  },
```

I'm completely confused. How can you select the correct text with questions and answers from one array of text and place the correct answer separately?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.